# $user-> removeRole('administrator') doesn't remove role

Tags: 8, users

I got php code that is suppouse to remove one role and add a new one to all users in given array. But unfortunatelly it just add new role but doesn't remove one. I tried alphanumeric values as `$rid` and straightforward numeric `$id` but still no effect. I tried putting error_logs inside loops and it's executed and printed to error_log.php.

**Here's my code**

```
foreach($users as $usr){
            $user = user_load_by_name($usr);
            $user->addRole('roleToAdd');
            $user->save();
        }
        foreach($users as $usr){
            $user = user_load_by_name($usr);
            $user->removeRole('roleToRemove');
            $user->save();
        }
}
```

**Array**

```
[0] => client1
[1] => client4
```

***#edit*** 
I think it is worth to mention that `roleToRemove` is assigned to every new user that is registered using [registration role module](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration_role)

## FIXED check answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found an answer.
The code is proper and it works. The problem was that I got module installed that assigned a role to new created users. I found out that it not only assign role when someone create new user but also when you was updating any of them. 
I've patched this bug and i got this hosted on my repo so if anybody needs it.
[repo](https://github.com/kwiniarski97/role_onregistration_patched)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Drupal code, it's absolutely clear that `removeRole` requires not the name but the id of the role:

https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.4.x/core/modules/user/src/Entity/User.php#L188

To test if the error happens in your own code or somewhere else, you could dump `$usr->getRoles()` immediately before and after executing it.

Comment: i tried it that way and still no results but i think that i found an error and it is not a code based one. The problem is that module that assigns a registration role assign it again on altering user.

Comment: id of role in drupal 8.x is name of role with all lower case and underscores instead of spaces i.e. `Role Name` becomes `role_name`